# Confused about date and time in Excel

Tags: java, excel, time, timezone, dst

I have Java time (ms since 1/1/1970 UTC) and would like to write that time to a csv file, so that Excel can correctly interpret and format it. I understand, that excel uses "serial date time" as a format - that is a floating point number, where the integer part gives the number of days since 1/1/1900 and the decimal part gives fractions of a day.

I fail to understand timezone and daylight saving time handling in this.

[This page](http://www.decimaltime.hynes.net/p/dates.html#excel)  says that the excel epoch (1/1/1900) is based on the local (=computer creating the Excel file?) timezone. This means that a serial date does not indicate a unique instant in time without the info which computer timezone created it. Not what I would have chosen, but OK.

Now accepting this, I believed I could convert Java time to Excel serial date by the following Java code (nb: I'm in Zurich, CET timezone):

```
private static final long ONE_HOUR= 60L * 60 * 1000;
private static final long ONE_DAY = 24 * ONE_HOUR;
private static final long excelEpoch; 
static{
    Calendar cal;
    cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Zurich"));
    cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 1900);
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

    excelEpoch = cal.getTimeInMillis();
}
private static String formatForExcel(long time){
    return ""+(time-excelEpoch)/(double)ONE_DAY;
}
```

Using this I can print out a few times:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String sep = "\t"; // csv field separator

    SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss d/M/yyyy");       
    fmt.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Zurich"));


    System.out.println("Time in ms since 1/1/1970 UTC"+ sep + "Time as string" + sep + "Excel serial" + sep + "Excel serial formatted by excel");
    long startTime = 1332630000000L; // 25/3/2012 00:00 CET , shortly before change from winter time to DST
    for (long t = startTime;  t < startTime + 4*ONE_HOUR; t+=ONE_HOUR) {
        System.out.println(t + sep + fmt.format(new Date(t)) + sep + formatForExcel(t) + sep + formatForExcel(t));
    }
}
```

Which returns

```
Time in ms since 1/1/1970 UTC   Time as string  Excel serial    Excel serial formatted by excel
1332630000000   00:00:00 25/3/2012  40991.0 40991.0
1332633600000   01:00:00 25/3/2012  40991.041666666664  40991.041666666664
1332637200000   03:00:00 25/3/2012  40991.083333333336  40991.083333333336
1332640800000   04:00:00 25/3/2012  40991.125   40991.125
```

Note that the change from winter time to DST happens in those hours (check second column, hour 2 is missing).

Now comes the confusion. If I paste this in excel, and for the last column choose "Format cells..." and then "Time" (any of the formats), it prints:

```
Time in ms since 1/1/1970 UTC   Time as string  Excel serial    Excel serial formatted by excel
1332630000000   25.03.2012 00:00    40991   0:00:00
1332633600000   25.03.2012 01:00    40991.04167 1:00:00
1332637200000   25.03.2012 03:00    40991.08333 2:00:00
1332640800000   25.03.2012 04:00    40991.125   3:00:00
```

Note, that excel in formatting the serial date, does not change to DST. So this is not wallclock time.

Long story short:

**How should I convert Java time to Excel so that it just works?**

Comment: As crazy as it sounds, "[Excel has no native concept of universal time. All times are specified in the local time zone](https://docs.sheetjs.com/#dates)". How geographically distributed teams agreed on what a timestamp meant (back when people used to email/FTP Excel files), must've been really fun.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I *suspect* that Excel doesn't really take the time zone into account. I suspect it's really just treating it as a "local time" where every conceivable date/time is valid. (A "local instant" in Joda Time parlance, I believe - although I don't know how widely that's used.)

I suspect there's no way of representing a specific *instant* in time, and that instead you should:

- Take whatever date/time you want to represent as a *local* time (e.g. "25th March 2012, 3am")
- Put that into a `Calendar` which is set to use UTC
- Take the millis from `calendar.getTime().getTime()`
- Subtract the "Excel epoch" value of 1900-01-01T00:00:00Z (again, obtain via a calendar which is set to UTC)
- Divide by "millis per day"

Now there's *also* an [oddity with Excel in terms of its handling of dates before March 1st 1900](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/214326), but hopefully that won't bite you.

Comment: Thinking about again in light of your comment, serial date is fundamentally broken, even if it were to indicate a unique instant (epoch in UTC), as the day fraction (decimal part) would have to represent 23 hours on the day of the DST change. That day is indeed an hour shorter. I understand you comment as: just use a formatted string as a time and let Excel sort it out by letting it parse the string. Not so satisfying. :-(

Comment: @Philipp: Not quite - I suspect Excel just doesn't do any time zone handling at all with this. There's no need to worry about days of unequal lengths if you don't deal with time zones :)

Comment: here is more information on the Excel bug: [KB 214326](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/214326). It affects only dates before March 1, 1900.

Comment: @Jon: So serial date is just another format for writing a date like "25/3/2012 02:00:00". It doesn't carry any more information. Obviously the timezone is lacking, but there's also an ambiguity on the day of DST - winter time change, as on that day I 2am happens twice. Even given the timezone, (say "Europe/Zurich"), "28/10/2012 02:00:00" is ambiguous and stands for two times. Isn't half the banking world running on Excel? Makes you wonder how that keeps working.

Comment: @Philipp: Yes - it's fundamentally a "local date/time", rather than a "zoned date/time"... it doesn't represent a single globally unique instant, and may be ambiguous or invalid when interpreted in a specific time zone.

Comment: @JonSkeet Answer is not clear, Can you give some example code?

Comment: @KanagaveluSugumar: Which step is causing you difficulties?

Comment: @JonSkeet For me JCONSOLE graph output time in CSV is like 41953.22985. I want to convert that to "11/10/2014  5:30:00 AM". I am able to do that in Excel; but want that programatically.

Comment: @KanagaveluSugumar: That sounds like the opposite situation to this question, which is converting *to* an Excel date. But you should be able to just reverse the steps, and format the `java.util.Date` afterwards...

Answer (score 0):

Convert floating point **"serial date/time" to "mills since 1970/1/1"**

Note: daysFrom1900to1970  works for google spreadsheet dates, but might need slight adjustment for excel

```
                            int daysFrom1900to1970 =365*70 + 19; // Or maybe =365*70 + 17 But 19 worked.
                            int millisPerDay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
                            long millisSince1970 = (long) ((timeToSend.doubleValue() - daysFrom1900to1970) * millisPerDay );

                            Calendar dateTimeToSend = Calendar.getInstance();                               
                            dateTimeToSend.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
                            dateTimeToSend.setTimeInMillis(millisSince1970);
                            System.out.println("timeToSend:"+ new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss z").format(dateTimeToSend.getTime()));
```